# Prove: Conformal map $w(z)$ transforms a trajectory in potential $U(z)=|dw/dz|^2$ to one in potential $V(z)=-|dz/dw|^2$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, complex-numbers

This is a conclusion given without proof in the Chinese version of Arnold's *Methematical Methods in Classical Mechancs*.
Contents related to this conclusion are missing from the English version (I guess they were added by the Chinese translator).

Years ago, I have found a [proof](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036144598346005) (on page 121) of a special case:
for the trajectory in the force field of power $a$ (i.e. $\mathbf F\propto\hat{\mathbf r}r^a$),
if we regard it as a curve in the complex plane and find the $\alpha$th power of the it,
we get a trajectory in the force field of power $A$, where $(a+3)\,(A+3)=4$, and $\alpha=(a+3)/2$.
The proof utilizes the conservation of energy and a new time parameter $\tau$ with the relation to the old time $t$ being $\mathrm d\tau/\mathrm d t=|z|^{a+1}$.

However, I cannot prove the more general result: conformal map $w(z)$ transforms a trajectory in potential $U(z):=|dw/dz|^2$ to one in another potential $V(w):=-|dz/dw|^2$.
I tried using $\mathrm d\tau/\mathrm d t=|w/z|^2$ with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result is proven in V.I. Arnold *Huygens and Barrow, Newton and Hooke* Appendix 1. This may be done by utilizing the Maupertuis principle:
$$\sqrt{2\left(E-U(z)\right)}\left|dz\right|=\sqrt E\sqrt{2\left(E'-V(w)\right)}\left|dw\right|,\quad EE'=-1.$$
This means that the dual trajectories have the same abbreviated action, so one of them being physical would imply that the other is physical too.

A more comprehensive discussion about this problem is available [here](https://ulysseszh.github.io/physics/2023/12/22/conformal-trajectory.html).